# Simple example for Intent and Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I'm new to android with almost no knowledge about Java and XML.
I'm learning it through pdfs that i'm getting on net.
I have learnt about Toast, a bit about Intents but me not able to understand anything about Bundles. I have understood that they are used to pass data from one activity to another but I'm not able to implement this.

please give a simple example to implement the same.

as for example I have just created two activities namely , Main_Activity and Other_Activity, and i haven't done anything to them yet.

Please give the simplest example so that i can learn to implement.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you need how pass the values between two activities

Comment: Activity xml tags are children of application. This threw me.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For example :

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.KEY_EXTRA, yourDataObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

In OtherActivity :

```
public static final String KEY_EXTRA = "com.example.yourapp.KEY_BOOK";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String yourDataObject = null;

  if (getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_EXTRA)) {
      yourDataObject = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA);
  } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity cannot find  extras " + KEY_EXTRA);
  }
  // do stuff
}
```

More informations here : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 24):

Try this: if you need pass values between the activities you use this...

This is code for Main_Activity put the values to intent

```
 String name="aaaa";
 Intent intent=new Intent(Main_Activity.this,Other_Activity.class);
 intent.putExtra("name", name);
 startActivity(intent);
```

This code for Other_Activity and get the values form intent

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = b.getString("name");
```

Comment: Note that 2 of the lines of code above can be made into 1: `Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();`

Comment: When you are retrieving from a bundle, get it as

Answer (score 8):

Basically this is what you need to do:
in the first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(tag, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activtiy:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getBooleanExtra(tag, defaultValue);
intent.getStringExtra(tag, defaultValue);
intent.getIntegerExtra(tag, defaultValue);
```

one of the get-functions will give return you the value, depending on the datatype you are passing through.