# Activity details lost when navigating to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, state, android-lifecycle

When I navigate away from an activity with calculation results,for example to check the diagrams in the help activity and I select the back button in action bar,the calculation have been reset to null.

I know there must be some way of setting the state of the activity to `pause` instead of having it stopped when I navigate away.

Does anyone know how I would achieve this in code? Is there a way to set the activity so that it doesn't destroy when the user leaves it? Also if I was to set this,would that calculation be fixed to that activity or would it refresh when I recalculate?

The code for the action bar back button is like this:

```
        final Button actionBarHome = (Button)actionBarLayout.             
        findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        actionBarHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent2);

            }

        });
```

[image: Calculated resut!]

[image: Navigated away and clicked back button]

[image: Results cleared]

Comment: Try messing around with the Bundle?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the bundle states,I have just started developing on Android from Java.

Comment: Now is the time to learn: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-the-importance-of-bundle-in-a-android-program

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity lifecycle is out of your hands really. You should be handling resuming your activity yourself. Putting your data into the bundle of onSaveInstanceState and using the savedInstanceState Bundle in onCreate to repopulate your views.

You can refer to this article [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: So what I'm thinking in this situation is:

Comment: `static final String OFFSET_LENGTH = "offsetlength"; public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putdouble(OFFSET_LENGTH, mark1);  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); `

Comment: And then to recall the data when I load the activity like this inside onCreate?    `if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        marl1 = savedInstanceState.getInt(OFFSET_LENGTH);`

Comment: I tried the above,so when I created the `onSaveInstanceState` and I use `.putDouble` it doesn't recognise the variable `mark1` that I want to save from the calculation.Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: @BrianJ You're using putDouble but getInt?

Comment: Okay yes I have changed that,but the mark1,calculation variable is still not being recognised..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that mark1 isn't recognised. You should probably make another question for this issue.