# Value of a Variable Don't change for using in another class

Tags: android, variables

sorry I'm really Amateur.
i have 4 class: A B C D.
I want to calculate something in my Class C and show the result in Class D but i have no idea why my app always show Zero as result in Class D!!!

Here is brief of my codes:

Class C:

```
public class ClassC extends Activity {

            public static int Result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ClassC);

                    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);

                         Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
                 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                            boolean b = cb.isChecked();

                            if (ClassA.MyVazn() < 251 ){
            Result = 26500;
            }
            else if (ClassA.MyVazn() >= 251 && ClassA.MyVazn() <= 500){
            Result = 31800;
            }

            else {
            Result = 38700;
                            }

                            if (b){
                            Result += 12000;
                            }

                            Intent a = new Intent (ClassC.this,ClassD.class);
            startActivity(a);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.a,R.anim.b);

                        }
            }

            public static int FinalResult (){
        return Result;
    }




}
```

Class D

```
public class ClassD extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ClassD);


        TextView r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
        r.setText(String.valueOf(ClassC.FinalResult()));
      }
}
```

help plz :(

Comment: use bundle to send data from one activity to another. here's what the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle) for what you have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all but i has found my problem, the code that is here is all Ok , and problem caused for my ClassB that never compiled because Defined some code to skip it in some special condition!
and then i tried to get value of my methods in ClassB!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Result` is not calculated in `ClassC` until something is clicked, but you are trying to read it in `ClassD`'s `onCreate` method, before the calculation has occurred.

You probably need to move the following line to some part of your code that runs **after** the click.

```
    r.setText(String.valueOf(ClassC.FinalResult()));
```

Answer (score 0):

because class C probably does not exist anymore. send the result in the intent

```
Intent a = new Intent (ClassC.this,ClassD.class);
a.putExtra("result",result);
startActivity(a);
```

then in your ClassD get it

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int resultFromActivity = i.getIntExtra("result",someDefaultValue);

TextView r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
r.setText(String.valueOf(resultFromActivity));
```