# Bundle does not exist in the mainActivity when returned from a sub activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult, start-activity

I started an sub activity for results and it retuen a bundle contains some data to the parent activity.

the problem is, in the parent activtiy in the `onActivityResult()` method, i checked if there is a bundle returned from the sub activity with a specific name

`bunConnAssets`

but the if-condition in the switch-case suggests that there is no bundle with the given name

please let me know where is my error.

**in subActivity**:

```
if (this.mqttSettingsDB != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "this.mqttSettingsDB is not null.");

        int[] id = this.mqttSettingsDB.getIDs();
        Bundle bunConnAssets = new Bundle();
        Intent intConnAssets = new Intent();
        ....
        ....
        ....

        intConnAssets.putExtras(bunConnAssets);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intConnAssets);
```

**MainActivity**:

```
switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == MainActivityA.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.hasExtra("bunConnAssets")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bundle exists");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bundle does not exist");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "resultCode != RESULT_OK");
        }
```

**LogCat**:

```
02-03 12:36:38.737: W/SettingsActivity(12659): @finish().
02-03 12:36:38.737: D/SettingsActivity(12659): this.mqttSettingsDB is not null.
02-03 12:36:38.957: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(12659): @onPause().
```

Comment: Are you sure `Log.d(TAG, "this.mqttSettingsDB is not null.");` is executed? Can you update your question with logcat?

Comment: @Sufian yes sure, updated the post with logcat

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle

Comment: @rmaik and how are you starting the activity?

Comment: startActivity for results

Comment: Paste the line. I think you're making some mistake, either in starting the activity or somewhere in the `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Bundle using below code

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
if (extras!=null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Bundle exists");
     } else {
     Log.d(TAG, "Bundle does not exist");   
   }
```