# How can I send my Database and other Objects from MainActivity to my Fragment?

Tags: android, database, android-fragments

I've just started working with Android and I find this so hard to understand. What I have is three different fragments and I'm using a NavigationDrawerFragment to go between the fragments. I want to display information from my database in these different fragmets in ListViews.

This is the code in my **MainActivity** that creates the Database and how the app goes between fragments.

```
...
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
private CollectionEmployee allEmployees;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up database.
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    allEmployees =  new CollectionEmployee(dbHandler.getAllContacts(), dbHandler);
    allEmployees.addEmployee(new Employee(10,"Kim D","07","da@gmail.com","ki3"));

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment myFragment;

    switch(position){
        case 0: myFragment = new FragmentEmoployees();
            break;
        case 1: myFragment = new FragmentProjects();
            break;
        case 2: myFragment = new FragmentDomains();
            break;
        default: myFragment = new FragmentEmoployees();
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, myFragment)
            .commit();
}
...
```

This is my class **FragmentEmployee** where I want to display all the employees, from the Database in my **MainActivity**, in a ListView.

```
public class FragmentEmoployees extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private ListView listViewEmployees;


/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentEmoployees.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentEmoployees newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentEmoployees fragment = new FragmentEmoployees();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee, container, false);
    listViewEmployees = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewEmployees);

    //Set up listview so it displays all employees from database.. but how?...

    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

The information of the employees are in a Collection-class so I find it relevant to just send variable "allEmployees" to my **EmployeeFragment**. But the only help I can find is how to send simple Strings by using Bundle and getArguments(). Could I make my class variables in MainActivity static or is that a bad idea? I'm trying to have loose coupling.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: *I'm trying to have loose coupling* ... then do this in right way: use `ContentProvider` and pass just employee's uri to fragment (like: `content://my.super.authority/emoployees/1`) fragment should take care of loading the data from ContentProvider by itself ...

Comment: Okey thanks alot! I'll try this, though reading the documentation I find this even harder to understand.

Comment: Implementing ContentProvide is not an easy job ... but once you will get it you will never want to use other stuff(like ORM/POJO) anymore on android platform(it is just my opinion :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intent or Bundle to pass information from one activity to other Fragments.
Example:
[Simple example for Intent and Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle)