# Retrieve data from server and send it to next activity

Tags: php, android

I retrieve the data from server using php, I want send it to next activity

I already retrieve the id and name, How can I store it and send to next activity

This is my list view

```
private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] viewstudent= new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            viewstudent[i] = obj.getString("id") + " " + obj.getString("name");

           //is here store it for send to next activity?

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewstudent);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {


               //I think here maybe send data to next activity
                
            }


        });
```

Have any simple way? Can give me some example?

Comment: Use `intent.putExtra`. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SharedPreferences to save simple data types like

```
String, Integer, Boolean, Long, Short, ...
```

To send data to another activity you use bundle.

- Shared Preferences To Store Data

1. To get shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2. Store data to Shared Preferences:

```
prefs.edit().putLong("Id_KEY", myUserId).apply();
```

3. To read data from Shared Preferences

```
int userId = prefs.getInt("Id_KEY", -1);
```

- Bundles to send data to another activity

1. Send data to SecondActivity from FirstActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_ID_KEY", myUserId);
        startActivity(intent
    );
```

2. Receive Data from FirstActivity:

```
overide void onCreate(...) {
   ...
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String userId = intent.getStringExtra("ACTIVITY_ID_KEY", -1);
   ...
}
```

Comment: the 1 and 2 is write in my loadIntoListView?

Comment: the 3 is write in lv.setOnItemClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data json by use Gson and create Java class from jsonschema2pojo.org.

To send data to next activiy, you can use Bundle.